# Parsing Google Maps Geocoder JSON results depending on route type

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have spent a few hours trying to find the best way of parsing the result JSON object that is returned from Geocoder.  I have developed a routine but it appears inconsistent and present an example where the "types:["route"] is not parsed.  This is frustrating because all I want is the Road Name from all the data is returned.

The code I am using is simply:

```
     var startGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     startGeocoder.geocode({'latLng': start}, function(results, status) {
     for (var key in results){
        var add = results[key];
        for (var key2 in add.types) {
           alert (JSON.stringify(add.types[key2]))
           if ((add.types[key2].localeCompare('route')) == 0)
             alert (JSON.stringify(add.address_components[0]['long_name']))
           }
        }
     });
```

The above code when run against the typical field below identifies every `type` except the `route`.

Is anyone able to shine any light on this for me please?

Here is a typical result field:

```
    [  
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"355",
        "short_name":"355",
        "types":[  
           "street_number"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Hancock Road",
        "short_name":"Hancock Rd",
        "types":[  
           "route"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Fairview Park",
        "short_name":"Fairview Park",
        "types":[  
           "locality",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"City of Tea Tree Gully",
        "short_name":"Tea Tree Gully",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_2",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"5126",
        "short_name":"5126",
        "types":[  
           "postal_code"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"355 Hancock Rd, Fairview Park SA 5126, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-34.8008008,
        "west":138.71713069999998,
        "north":-34.7992395,
        "east":138.71723040000006
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-34.8005542,
        "lng":138.7172365
     },
     "location_type":"RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-34.8013691302915,
        "west":138.71583156970848,
        "north":-34.7986711697085,
        "east":138.71852953029156
     }
      },
      "place_id":"EjAzNTUgSGFuY29jayBSZCwgRmFpcnZpZXcgUGFyayBTQSA1MTI2LCBBdXN0cmFsaWE",
      "types":[  
     "street_address"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"Stop 57A Hancock Rd - East side",
        "short_name":"Stop 57A Hancock Rd - East side",
        "types":[  
           "establishment",
           "point_of_interest"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Fairview Park",
        "short_name":"Fairview Park",
        "types":[  
           "locality",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Adelaide",
        "short_name":"Adelaide",
        "types":[  
           "colloquial_area",
           "locality",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"City of Tea Tree Gully",
        "short_name":"Tea Tree Gully",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_2",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"5126",
        "short_name":"5126",
        "types":[  
           "postal_code"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Stop 57A Hancock Rd - East side, Fairview Park SA 5126, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "location":{  
        "lat":-34.8006135,
        "lng":138.71727480000004
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-34.8019624802915,
        "west":138.71592581970845,
        "north":-34.7992645197085,
        "east":138.71862378029152
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJn8pNYzWzsGoRx1bLlLZmZ90",
      "types":[  
     "bus_station",
     "establishment",
     "point_of_interest",
     "transit_station"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"Fairview Park",
        "short_name":"Fairview Park",
        "types":[  
           "locality",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"City of Tea Tree Gully",
        "short_name":"Tea Tree Gully",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_2",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"5126",
        "short_name":"5126",
        "types":[  
           "postal_code"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Fairview Park SA 5126, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-34.8056301,
        "west":138.71677679999993,
        "north":-34.7943156,
        "east":138.74573839999994
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-34.7999009,
        "lng":138.7316925
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-34.8056301,
        "west":138.71677679999993,
        "north":-34.7943156,
        "east":138.74573839999994
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJawxGOM5Mt2oRkK-OYlQ2AwU",
      "types":[  
     "locality",
     "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"Adelaide",
        "short_name":"Adelaide",
        "types":[  
           "colloquial_area",
           "locality",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Adelaide SA, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-35.3489699,
        "west":138.44212990000005,
        "north":-34.652564,
        "east":138.78018980000002
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-34.9284989,
        "lng":138.60074559999998
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-35.3489699,
        "west":138.4421843,
        "north":-34.652564,
        "east":138.78018980000002
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJP7Mmxcc1t2oRQMaOYlQ2AwQ",
      "types":[  
     "colloquial_area",
     "locality",
     "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"5126",
        "short_name":"5126",
        "types":[  
           "postal_code"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Yatala Vale",
        "short_name":"Yatala Vale",
        "types":[  
           "locality",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"City of Tea Tree Gully",
        "short_name":"Tea Tree Gully",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_2",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Yatala Vale SA 5126, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-34.8064724,
        "west":138.70020479999994,
        "north":-34.7851545,
        "east":138.75147430000004
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-34.7978361,
        "lng":138.72667209999997
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-34.8064724,
        "west":138.70020479999994,
        "north":-34.7851545,
        "east":138.75147430000004
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJawxGOM5Mt2oR8AtRo1c2Axw",
      "postcode_localities":[  
     "Fairview Park",
     "Surrey Downs",
     "Yatala Vale"
      ],
      "types":[  
     "postal_code"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"City of Tea Tree Gully",
        "short_name":"Tea Tree Gully",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_2",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Tea Tree Gully, SA, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-34.8691732,
        "west":138.6596839,
        "north":-34.734253,
        "east":138.78018980000002
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-34.8300729,
        "lng":138.69906790000005
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-34.8691732,
        "west":138.6596839,
        "north":-34.734253,
        "east":138.78018980000002
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJ-wqJpspMt2oRrRs6Lwie980",
      "types":[  
     "administrative_area_level_2",
     "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"North Eastern Suburbs",
        "short_name":"North Eastern Suburbs",
        "types":[  
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"North Eastern Suburbs, SA, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-34.8894817,
        "west":138.61869439999998,
        "north":-34.7443817,
        "east":138.7861792
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-34.8300729,
        "lng":138.69906790000005
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-34.8894817,
        "west":138.61869439999998,
        "north":-34.7443817,
        "east":138.7861792
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJ3exKbqG0sGoRP2y5TCm9g0Q",
      "types":[  
     "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"Adelaide Metropolitan Area",
        "short_name":"Adelaide Metropolitan Area",
        "types":[  
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Adelaide Metropolitan Area, SA, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-35.3502961,
        "west":138.43563900000004,
        "north":-34.6129929,
        "east":138.84804329999997
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-34.9536465,
        "lng":138.59880399999997
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-35.3502961,
        "west":138.43563900000004,
        "north":-34.6129929,
        "east":138.84804329999997
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJy52tqNXOsGoRHrTedC1y5i4",
      "types":[  
     "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"South Australia",
        "short_name":"SA",
        "types":[  
           "administrative_area_level_1",
           "political"
        ]
     },
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"South Australia, Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-38.1345913,
        "west":129.00134000000003,
        "north":-25.9963765,
        "east":141.00295559999995
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-30.0002315,
        "lng":136.2091547
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-38.0611336,
        "west":129.00138519999996,
        "north":-25.9963765,
        "east":141.00295529999994
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJ88foW55Yp2oR2ND6PZl5fts",
      "types":[  
     "administrative_area_level_1",
     "political"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "address_components":[  
     {  
        "long_name":"Australia",
        "short_name":"AU",
        "types":[  
           "country",
           "political"
        ]
     }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Australia",
      "geometry":{  
     "bounds":{  
        "south":-54.83376579999999,
        "west":110.95103389999997,
        "north":-9.187026399999999,
        "east":159.28722229999994
     },
     "location":{  
        "lat":-25.274398,
        "lng":133.77513599999997
     },
     "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
     "viewport":{  
        "south":-51.66332320000001,
        "west":100.09110720000001,
        "north":-0.6911343999999999,
        "east":166.74291670000002
     }
      },
      "place_id":"ChIJ38WHZwf9KysRUhNblaFnglM",
      "types":[  
     "country",
     "political"
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types array you need to parse is in the address_components array of each entry.

```
{  
  "address_components":[  
  {  
    "long_name":"Hancock Road",
    "short_name":"Hancock Rd",
    "types":[  
       "route"
    ]
  },
```

code to parse:

```
var startGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var start = {lat:-34.8005542,lng:138.7172365};
startGeocoder.geocode({
  'latLng': start
}, function(results, status) {
  for (var key in results) {
    var add = results[key];
    for (var key2 in add.address_components) {
      var add2 = add.address_components[key2];
      for (var key3 in add2.types) {
        if ((add2.types[key3].localeCompare('route')) == 0)
          alert(JSON.stringify(add2['long_name']))
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q04e65gz/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var startGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var start = {
    lat: -34.8005542,
    lng: 138.7172365
  };
  startGeocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': start
  }, function(results, status) {
    for (var key in results) {
      var add = results[key];
      console.log(add);
      for (var key2 in add.address_components) {
        var add2 = add.address_components[key2];
        console.log(add2);
        for (var key3 in add2.types) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(add2.types[key3]))
          if ((add2.types[key3].localeCompare('route')) == 0)
            alert(JSON.stringify(add2['long_name']))
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the answer - thankyou.  So obvious once pointed out!